# Checksum for DB2 fixpack

Tags: db2

Where can I find the checksum result for a fixpack. I am downloading files, but they got corrupted.
I cannot find an MD5 value in Fixpack central.
Does anybody know if IBM publish them?
Does Download Directory checks a checksum, or it is just like any regular download manager?